# What could be wrong with my config.php?

Tags: php, html, css, image

My config.php code:

```
define("SITEFOLDER", "adamsProject");
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "D:\\\\xampp\htdocs\\". SITEFOLDER . "\\css");
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "D:\\\\xampp\htdocs\\" . SITEFOLDER . "\\includes");
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "D:\\\\xampp\htdocs\\" . SITEFOLDER . "\\pages");
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "D:\\\\xampp\htdocs\\" . SITEFOLDER . "\\images");
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "D:\\\\xampp\htdocs\\" . SITEFOLDER . "\\js");
```

And my contactUs.php page code:

```
session_start();
include_once "../includes/config.php";
include_once "navMain.php";
```

navMain.php => HTML OUTPUT

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logoMain.png" id="logoMain"></a> 
        <li><a href="index.php"> HOME </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="servicesWide"> SERVICES <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></li>
        <li> <a href="underConstruction.php"> ABOUT US </a></li>
        <li> <a href="underConstructionIf.php"> CONTACT US </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" id="folioWide"> PORTFOLIO <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

What could be wrong. Images links are still broken.

Comment: Check the source for broken links and see what it is printing.

Comment: Rest assured. No links are broken.

Comment: *Images links are still broken.* - check the image links. Are they proper.

Comment: A `"` ( double quote ) seems to be missing before `D:\ ` in the second line of your code .

Comment: Double quotes are ok. I just messed  up typing it here. Nevertheless, edit carried on.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
You use for 5 times set_include_path with another path and get_included_path. So I think you extend the include path with your own code.

Your path's are wrong.

I think D:\ is your drive letter, so this should be part of the string.

> But there's still the problem that you override your include path. You call the set_include_path 5 times! Code below is a pseudo, because I don't know the complete logic of set_include_path. That's why I suppose to set the include path 1 time.

```
define("SITEFOLDER", "adamsProject");
set_include_path("D:\\\\xampp\htdocs\\". SITEFOLDER);
```

Above is the root path, so you can use such as:

```
echo get_include_path() . '/images/file.png';
```

> You use your application path + absolute path from D:\XAMPP. I recommend to use application path only, because it's easier for you to go live with your applications (no need to change path's if you use the application path instead of absolute path's from your drive letter).

Comment: Yup, I'm developing a site in my localhost. So, I'm using drive D: since my xampp is intalled in that drive. Later, I'll upload it to the remote server.

Comment: @ROLDANKING please press `ctrl + u` to view page source and post it in your question.

Comment: @Hassan Pasted above. That's the navMain.php pasted in contactUs.php page through `include_once "navMain.hp"`

Comment: @Henri S. This came out after echoing: `.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR/includes/navMain.php`